# Inserting a new row on a DataFrame and and pasting the contents of another row to that new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to insert a new row into my dataframe on to a specific index. And once I have done so I want to copy and paste the contents of another row into that new row created and delete the old row. I managed to create an empy row using numpy but the problem is that it changes the column names to number. Please assist.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"var1": ["AZZBBAA", "CCDDDED", "DZZZZFD", "CDEEEEFG"],
                  "var2": [1,2,4,5]})
Output is :

    var1       var2
0   AZZBBAA     1
1   CCDDDED     2
2   DZZZZFD     4
3   CDEEEEFG    5

#inserting a new row:

import  numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 2,'', axis=0))

#output is below.
    0         1
0   AZZBBAA   1
1   CCDDDED   2
2
3   DZZZZFD   4
4   CDEEEEFG  5
```

The ouput above does insert a new row, but it now changes the column names.

My desired output is where I can copy row 4`index3` ```CDEEEEEFG 5```` into the now new row on index 2 and delete the one that I copied.

```
#desired output
    var1      var2
0   AZZBBAA     1
1   CCDDDED     2
2   CDEEEEFG    5
3   DZZZZFD     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think inserting is not necessary - only rename indices for specify new order, then add [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for expected ouput:

```
n = 2
m = 3

df = df.rename({m: n-0.5}).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
print (df)
       var1  var2
0   AZZBBAA     1
1   CCDDDED     2
2  CDEEEEFG     5
3   DZZZZFD     4
```

Comment: What does the 0.5 mean?

Comment: @thole - it is way for append `m` row before `n` - here between `1` and `2` indices

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order of the dataframe indices you'd like then you can just use iloc since you're just copying contents from one row to another anyway. Just reorder your dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"var1": ["AZZBBAA", "CCDDDED", "DZZZZFD", "CDEEEEFG"],
                  "var2": [1,2,4,5]})
df2 = df.iloc[[0, 1, 3, 2]].reset_index()

Out[43]: 
   index      var1  var2
0      0   AZZBBAA     1
1      1   CCDDDED     2
2      3  CDEEEEFG     5
3      2   DZZZZFD     4
```